# XML Layout Alternative (mine gets a Lint warning)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ListView` in which each row is a `GridLayout` with two rows.  I want each list item to be at least 48dp high (recommended minimum size for press targets) because each can be pressed, and I want the `GridLayout` to be vertically centered in the row if it doesn't expand it.

To do this, I've put the `GridLayout` inside a `FrameLayout`, set the `FrameLayout` to a minimum height of 48dp, and set the `layout_gravity` of the `GridLayout` to center.  If I don't use the `FrameLayout` and just set the minimum height of the `GridLayout`, then I can't get the whole thing nicely vertically centered because of `GridLayout`'s bogus space distribution.

So, using the `FrameLayout` gives me the desired outcome, but generates a Lint warning in my XML file, "This GridLayout layout or its FrameLayout parent is useless."  Obviously it's not useless since it lines stuff up right, but is there a better way to do it that I missed?

Here is my XML (I cut out a bunch of TextViews in the GridLayout because they're not relevant to this situation):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
>
<GridLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:minEms="1"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:minEms="2"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:minEms="3"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/c"
         android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:minEms="3"
    />
    ...
</GridLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried also setting `android:gravity="center"` in your grid layout.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, didn't work.  The problem is that you can't make GridLayout distribute space evenly among rows/columns.  It will expand the last row/column to fill the remaining space, which completely screws up attempts to center it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're seeing a performance problem, I'd just keep it that way. If you're seeing a performance problem, and it's *because* of the additional FrameLayout (you can tell that if the problem goes away if you use GridLayout directly), then (and only then) I'd try fixing  the GridLayout directly.

If that's the case, then what I know is that GridLayout distributes excess space according to the principle of *flexibility*. If that principle is not enough to disambiguate, then you'd see the behavior where it gives the excess space to the rightmost column and bottom row. I'd try to play with the row/col attributes to make sure that it understands how to distribute that evenly. You can control that by setting the *gravity* of the children of the GridLayout, in your case the TextViews. Try setting them to 'center', and see if that helps. If not, more info at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll just leave it as is I guess.  I know how GridLayout works, it just sucks that you can't have it distribute evenly.